# javascript one class per file using eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I would like to use javascript classes with one class per file.  It is part of a larger project using eslint. I started with:

```
/*global CSReport*/
/*global CSManager*/
class CSMain {
    constructor() {
        this.report = new CSReport();
        this.manager = new CSManager(this.report);
    }
    launchReport(...
}
```

However, eslint generates an error saying CSMain is defined but never used.  This led to the idea of using export and import which seemed better than making everything global (side note: CS in front of main is the old style method to avoid global conflicts)

The question is how to put this together. The release version will be a single (uglified) file, so the class file names will no longer exist when they are all concatenated together in (say) csCompiled.js.

Questions:

1. Import uses a file name.  Should I use the CSCompiled.js name rather than the file names before concatenation?
2. Do I want a single module or a module for each class?
3. Do I need to export every class and import every class it uses?
4. I am not fully sure how angular accesses this code but am thinking to import csMain.

I tried to find an answer to this but am only finding older posts that don't use ecmascript 6 and classes.  If an answer to this exists, I am not sure how to get to it.

Background:
The main project uses angular 1.  This code is separate for legacy reasons.  It is currently written in java using gwt, but we want to move to javascript to remove the reliance on gwt.  It is about 30-40 files (classes) total to convert.

The code gets and handles data from the server for report requests. There is a lot of pre-processing done before it is handed back to the rest of the UI.

I have used javascript for an established project using angular, but lack expertise on how to create new projects.

I am trying to use basic javascript for this, so it won't need updating if (for example) we go from angular 1 to the current versions.  I do not yet know if this is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESLint is complaining because you are not exporting the class you created, therefore, it can't be accessed by other modules. You can fix that with a simple line at the end

```
export default CSMain;
```

> Import uses a file name. Should I use the CSCompiled.js name rather
>   than the file names before concatenation?

Use the file name before you compile/transpile/uglify/etc. After that it will all become 1 file and the bundler will take care of that for you.

> Do I want a single module or a module for each class?

Completely optional, I like to have 1 class per file and then 1 file for the module (index.js) that lists all classes in that module.

> Do I need to export every class and import every class it uses?

Yes, you need to import everything your module will use and export everything that should be public or "importable" for other modules.

> I am not fully sure how angular accesses this code but am thinking to import csMain.

It all depends on how you export your file. Make sure to import the same name your module/file is exporting.